# SQL sum of all unique values per date

Tags: sql, count, concatenation, return-value

So this will be my first inquiry, woo!

I'm trying to combine like values in a column per a corresponding date code. So for date 5213, using the example table below, I want to return in a sum of all possible combinations for the given events.

*Example table:*

```
╔══════╦═════════╦═════════╦═════════╗
║ Date ║ Event1  ║ Event2  ║ Event3  ║
╠══════╬═════════╬═════════╬═════════╣
║ 5213 ║    A    ║    C    ║    E    ║
║ 5213 ║    A    ║    D    ║    E    ║
║ 5212 ║    A    ║    D    ║    F    ║
║ 5212 ║    A    ║    C    ║    F    ║
║ 5212 ║    B    ║    D    ║    F    ║
║ 5212 ║    A    ║    D    ║    F    ║
║ 5212 ║    B    ║    D    ║    F    ║
╚══════╩═════════╩═════════╩═════════╝
```

*The return I would like to see:*

```
╔══════╦══════════════╦════════════════╗
║ Date ║ Comb_Event   ║ Count_of_Event ║
╠══════╬══════════════╬════════════════╣
║ 5213 ║     ACE      ║       1        ║
║ 5213 ║     ADE      ║       1        ║
║ 5212 ║     ADF      ║       2        ║
║ 5212 ║     ACF      ║       1        ║
║ 5212 ║     BDF      ║       2        ║
╚══════╩══════════════╩════════════════╝
```

I'm not sure how to concatenate values and furthermore how to count said values in a separate column. Any direction will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: which RDBMS it is mysql, sqlserver ?

Comment: -1 for no research effort; no platform

Comment: Sorry about that, first go at this. I'm working in sqlserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you combine values depends on the database.  That is the only tricky part of a question that is otherwise basic SQL.  Here is an example using the standard `concat()` function:

```
select date, concat(event1, event2, event3) as comb_event, count(*)
from example
group by date, concat(event1, event2, event3)
order by date, concat(event1, event2, event3);
```

Depending on the database, the syntax might be:

```
select date, event1 || event2 || event3 as comb_event, count(*)
from example
group by date, event1 || event2 || event3
order by date, event1 || event2 || event3;
```

or:

```
select date, event1 + event2 + event3 as comb_event, count(*)
from example
group by date, event1 + event2 + event3
order by date, event1 + event2 + event3;
```

or event:

```
select date, event1 & event2 & event3 as comb_event, count(*)
from example
group by date, event1 & event2 & event3
order by date, event1 & event2 & event3;
```

Comment: very thorough - I'll keep this in mind moving forward. With this I was able to solve my dilemma!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for both SQL Server and MySQL:

```
select count(*) as count_of_events, dates 
,concat(event1, event2, event3) as comb_event
from test
group by dates, concat(event1, event2, event3)
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78422/7)

Comment: Thanks rhealitycheck, this helped greatly.